# Why isn't $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Definition :  A ring R is a set R equipped with two binary operations $+$ and $\cdot$ on R satisfying the following conditions:

(1)  R is an abelian group under $+$.

(2)  $\cdot$ is associative and has an identity element.

(3a) $\cdot$ is left-distributive over $+$, that is, $a \cdot (b+c) = (a \cdot b) + (a \cdot c)$ for all a,b,c in R.

(3b) $\cdot$ is right-distributive over $+$, that is $(b+c) \cdot a = (b \cdot a) + (c \cdot a)$ for all a,b,c in R.

$GL_n(\mathbb{R}) = \{A \in M_n(\mathbb{R}) : det(A) \neq 0 \}$

I feel like property 1 fails, but I am unsure why.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: What would be your additive identity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, property (1) fails, because if $+$ denotes the usual addition of matrices, $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ isn't even closed under $+$.  For instance, if $I$ is the identity matrix, then $I\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $-I\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, but $I+(-I)=0\not\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense.

Comment: For the group of units mod n, would it also not be closed under addition since the group operation is multiplication?

Comment: Well, the fact that the group operation is multiplication doesn't in itself imply that it is not closed under addition.  To show it is not closed under addition, you should explicitly find two elements in the set whose sum is not in the set.

Answer (score 5):

Is the $0$ matrix 
in $GL_n(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my trivial question.

Answer (score 4):

You need a zero element in the ring. If $A+O = A$ then $O$ is necessarily in the ring. But the zero matrix isn't invertible as it has a zero determinant.

Answer (score 4):

$I$ and $-I$ are elements of $GL(n)$, but their sum isn't.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, the sum of two elements in $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is not necessarily invertible, so it is not closed under addition.

Answer (score 3):

If $A\in GL_n (\mathbb {R}) $, then $-A\in GL_n (\mathbb {R}) $, but $A+(-A)=0\notin GL_n (\mathbb {R})$.